# Concatenate many rows into a single text string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to concatenate several names into a single column but I'm having trouble getting there.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT 
    p.Pato_Id
    @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + e.First_Name + ' ' + e.Last_Name

FROM 
    Patos p

LEFT JOIN 
    Pato_Owners po
ON
    po.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    Person e
ON
    po.Owner_Id = e.Person_Id
```

How can this be done?

**EDIT:**

When I'm making a normal select I getting

```
PatoID First  Last 
0      John   Wort
0      Dan    Mass
1      Till   Bos
2      Wrap   Sim
2      Port   Lock
```

And what I want is:

```
PatoID Names
0      John Wort, Dan Mass
1      Till Bos
2      Wrap Sim, Port Lock
```

Comment: which sql server version ??

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this,

```
WITH Sales_CTE (Pato_Id, First, Last)
AS
(
Select p.Pato_Id , e.First , e.Last
FROM 
    Patos p
LEFT JOIN 
    Pato_Owners po
ON
    po.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    Person e
ON
    po.Owner_Id = e.Person_Id
)
SELECT Pato_Id,  
Substring((Select ',' + ISNULL(First,'') +  ISNULL(Last,'') From Sales_CTE B Where B.Pato_Id=A.Pato_Id For XML Path('')),2,8000) As names  
 from Sales_CTE A group by Pato_Id;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Answer (score 0):

You have left join which indicate that you can have null names. This would reset the values of names should that occur.

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT 
    p.Pato_Id,
    coalesce(e.First_Name, '') + coalesce(' ' + e.Last_Name, '') Name
FROM 
    Patos p

LEFT JOIN 
    Pato_Owners po
ON
    po.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    Person e
ON
    po.Owner_Id = e.Person_Id
)

select t.Pato_id
    ,STUFF(( 
        select ',' + [name] 
        from cte t1 
        where t1.Pato_Id = t.Pato_Id
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [Names] 
from cte t 
group by t.Pato_id
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Comment: @DKALT that is because you are not copying my entire script, you must omit 'p.Pato_id'

Comment: Yes, but I need several fields from p

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT 
p.Pato_Id,
'ServerName' = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + e.First_Name + ' ' + e.Last_Name

FROM 
Patos p

LEFT JOIN 
Pato_Owners po
ON
po.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
LEFT JOIN 
Person e
ON
po.Owner_Id = e.Person_Id
```

Comment: This will only concatenate the first and last name but not all records for that Patos